# how to store output of echo and cut to a variable

Tags: cat, cut

I have a file named test which has two columns one having ID and other having status.

I want to loop through the file and print IDs where status have one particular value (e.g. 'ACTIVE').

I tried
`cat test | while read line; do templine= $($line | cut -d ' ' -f 2);echo $templine; if [ $templine = 'ACCEPTED' ]; then   echo "$templine"; fi done`
and some variation of above which obviously did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `cat test | while read line; do templine= $($line | cut -d ' ' -f 2);echo $templine; if [[ $templine = 'ACCEPTED' ]]; then   echo "$templine"; fi done
`

above command treadted IDs as commands and started executing them

Comment: Have you considered just `grep`ping the lines and then getting the column of the IDs only?

Comment: egrep "[^[:space:]]*[:space:]ACTIVE" | awk ' { print $1 } '

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro that would be `awk '$2 == "ACTIVE" { print $1 }'` ;-)

Comment: Even better and more compact, I never remember to use awk´s BEGIN block. Thanks!

Comment: @StephenKitt worked like a charm! Thanks, I am a newbie with Unix and was struggling with this for quite some time now.

any idea why my query above did not work ?

Comment: your query didn't work because you had just `templine=$($line | cut ...)` rather than `$(echo "$line" | cut ...)` or, better yet: `$(printf '%s' "$line" | cut ...)`.  your version of the command attempted to execute the command contained in `$line` - which almost certainly doesn't exist.  you probably also wanted `cat test | while IFS= read line ; do ...` so that `read` assigns the entire input line to `$line` rather than just the first field.  but as has been mentioned awk is a better tool for this job.

Comment: See also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: @cas : Thanks for your suggestion
`cat test | while read line; do  templine= $(echo "$line" | cut  -f 2) ;   done;`
I made the changes as suggested but now it's executing the command contained in templine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to manipulate data in fields, `awk` tends to fit the bill quite nicely:

```
awk '$2 == "ACTIVE" { print $1 }' test
```

This reads each line of `test`, splits it into fields, then checks if the second one (`$2`) is `ACTIVE`; if so, it prints the first field.

Comment: another variation, if you want a regexp search on field 2 rather than an exact match, is: `awk '$2 ~ /ACTIVE/ { print $1 }'`

Comment: @StephenKitt worked like a charm! Thanks, I am a newbie with Unix and was struggling with this for quite some time now. any idea why my query above did not work ?

Comment: @AbhijeetShukla, the main problem in your attempt is `templine= $($line | cut -d ' ' -f 2)`, which runs `$line`; to fix that, `echo $line` instead, and remove the space after the `=`: `templine=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 2)`. If you want to use `read` you can use that to split the input into fields: `while read id status; do if [ "$status" = "ACTIVE" ]; then ...; fi; do`.

Answer (score 3):

see below example i hope its helpful for you

```
g=7

echo $g
```

output: 7

```
h=`echo $g`

echo $h
```

i hope its helpful for you see below image

[image]